# How to prevent "a program is trying to access data from Outlook..." warning for a trusted program

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office-interop

I have a C# WinForms application on a corporate network that should behave as a drag-and-drop target for emails in Outlook, i.e. I want to be able to drag and drop an email to my application. It is using the Office Interop libraries, v14 (for outlook 2010).

When dropping, Outlook gives a security warning, and an option to "allow access" for (1 | 5 | 10) minutes.

[image: security warning]

Other applications (e.g. Visual Studio, TRIM (a records management system), etc) allow dragging and dropping without any warning on the same machine. The security settings are managed by an administrator, and I don't have access to change them.

How do I prevent this from occuring for users of my application?

Is there a certificate I need to sign my app with? Do I need to register my app in some kind of registry?

Answer (score 2):

You get a standard security prompt in Outlook. "Security" in this context refers to the so-called "object model guard" that triggers security prompts and blocks access to certain features in an effort to prevent malicious programs from harvesting email addresses from Outlook data and using Outlook to propagate viruses and spam. These prompts cannot simply be turned off, except in latest Outlook versions with an anti-virus application running.

To avoid such security prompts you can:

1. Use a low-level API on which Outlook is based on instead of OOM. Or just any other third-party wrapper around that API (for example, such as Redemption).
2. Use [Outlook Security Manager](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) which allows to supress such warnings programmatically. Just a few lines of code is required.
3. In a corporate environment, the administrator may choose to loosen Outlook security for some or all users.
4. Create an Outlook COM add-in which doesn't trigger security prompts (all COM add-ins are trusted by default).

Read more about these ways in the [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=52) article.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for the information. I am guessing (based on the above), that Visual Studio, TFS, TRIM, and other applications that allow drag/drop have used one of the above approaches. I will read the links you've suggested, and see what I can come up with. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This prompt could surface if Outlook does not detect an Antivirus Solution installed on the host machine. In Outlook go to `File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Programmatic Access`

From here, you can override the recommended setting (not recommended) or Install a known Antivirus Solution.

[image: Antivirus Solution Not Detected]

Once a known Antivirus Solution is detected, the security prompt ceases to appear.

[image: Antivirus Solution Installed]